# Linux C Sockets - Binded socket receives packets from another interface?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, interface, packet

I'm working with Linux(Debian) and C.

I have opened a socket to the interfaces - eth0 and eth1 with the following function:

```
    // Opening the socket
    mSocket = socket(device->ifa_addr->sa_family, SOCK_RAW | SOCK_NONBLOCK,
                htons(ETH_P_ALL));
    if (mSocket == -1)
    {
        throw CException("socket is bad");
    }

    // Adding flag to the socket to work only on a specific interface
    if (setsockopt(mSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE,
            (void *) &mIfreq, sizeof(mIfreq)) < 0)
    {
        throw CException(
                "Failed to add binding to specific interface flag");
    }
```

while ifreq holds the interface name:

```
    strncpy(mIfreq.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name,device->ifa_name, IF_NAMESIZE);
```

The next thing I do is receiving packets using the following code:

```
    recvSize = recvfrom(mSocket, buffer, ETH_FRAME_LEN, 0, NULL,
                    NULL);
```

questions:

**1)** why if both interfaces aren't connected to anything non of the sockets can be opened

**2*)** why (WLOG) if eth0 is connected and eth1 isn't I can open sockets to each of them

**2.1*)** why by reading from eth1 socket I get all packets received in eth0

**(wireshark on eth1 isn't showing any packet as it should be)**

[my guess - is it linux fault?(doing stuff behind my back?)]

Thanks in advance,

Despair

Comment: What does `mIfreq` contain? how is it defined?

Comment: How does `throw CException(...)` and using C fit together?

Comment: ifreq was initialized with the ETH0/1 name only.

Comment: @glglgl would it make a difference if i use C libraries with C++ exceptions libraries?

Here to learn, thanks!

Comment: @Despair How would that help? You have no way to throw an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to capture raw data just as Wireshark does.

[socket(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) clearly states that `SO_BINDTODEVICE` is not applicable to packet sockets. You should `bind` your socket to `sockaddr_ll` type address with `sll_ifindex` field set to the interface number (see [packet(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/packet) for details). Interface number can be obtained from its name (like "eth0") using `SIOCGIFINDEX` `ioctl` (see [netdevice(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/netdevice)).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

I got ifaddr struct which holds `mIfreq.ifr_ifru.ifru_ivalue`
when i try to bind using that index i get failure
Invalid Argument.

do I miss any parameter?

Comment: `sockaddr_ll addr;
  addr.sll_family=AF_PACKET;
  addr.sll_ifindex=mInterfaceIndex; //2
  if(bind(mSocket,(sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(sockaddr))<0)
  {
   perror("Bind");
  }`

Comment: You probably should zero out the rest of the fields.
`sockaddr_ll addr = { 0 };`

Comment: ok found the problem. It should be `sizeof(sockaddr_ll)` ...

now eth0( the connected one ) only gets the packets
the problem now is that i dont get anything on the disconnected interface even after connecting it to a 3rd pinging device.
(wireshark shows them)
any idea?